# Jquery form with json no get values

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I have 2 files , one file for verification of form , writte in php , in this file i can get the next responses if the form it´s ok or bad :

```
print '{"captcha_error":"bad"}';
print '{"email_send":"bad"}';
print '{"email_request":"ok"}';
```

**For launch the form from the file 2 i use jquery with json :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send_contacter(idcc)
{

$.ajax({

cache: false,
url: 'send_form.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json', 
success: function(data) {



if (data.captcha_error=="bad")
{
alert("Captcha Error");
}

if (data.email_send=="bad")
{
alert("E-Mail Errors");
}

if (data.email_request=="ok")
{
alert("E-Mail Send");
}

}


});

}
</script>
```

**In the same page for submit i use one form as this :**

```
<?php 
$tfw_number_format="1";
?>

<form id="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>" class="contact-form-widget" method="post" action="" onsubmit="send_contacter('<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>');return false;" name="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>">
```

The problem i get it´s this , supose i go and use the form , right ? i receive one alert ok , but always it´s the same alert , the first alert , by other side if i go and launch the form and no use jquery all works fine , it´s as the jquery no launch the right and json retrieve bad the data and by this no detect the real data for show and discriminate betwen values , i think .....

By other side for verificate , if i use alert(""+data); always no receive values from json , always show me object object into the alert

I think i have something bad in my code

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: Open your console and see the errors and track the request 
& I think You need to use on submit for the form

Comment: I do this and no get errors that´s the problem

Comment: If you see my script i use onsbumit

Comment: Sorry about the on submit it was very far away , does your AJAX request reaches the PHP script try to make it die in PHP and see the console for the response

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the object properties are defined first.

```
if (data.captcha_error !== undefined && data.captcha_error=="bad") {
    alert("Captcha Error");
}

if (data.email_send !== undefined && data.email_send=="bad") {
    alert("E-Mail Errors");
}

if (data.email_request !== undefined && data.email_request=="ok") {
    alert("E-Mail Send");
}
```